# Prisma js return join fields

Tags: node.js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm trying to implement batching and caching with the [Facebook DataLoader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader). Let's say I have the following schema (taken from [here](https://v1.prisma.io/docs/1.34/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#overview)):

```
type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  published: Boolean! @default(value: false)
  author: User
  comments: [Comment!]!
}

type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String
  posts: [Post!]!
  comments: [Comment!]!
}

type Comment {
  id: ID! @id
  text: String!
  post: Post!
  writtenBy: User!
}
```

I am working on a tricky resolver which lists all comments created by the same user under the same post for a given comment. To retrieve a single entry I would go like:

```
const fetchCommentsByUserForSamePost = async (commentId: string, userId: string): Promise<Comment[]> => {
  const comments = await this.prisma.comment.findOne({ where: { id: commentId } })
    .post()
    .comments({
      where: {
        writtenBy: { id: userId }
      }
    })
  return comments;
}
```

This works well for a single query, but I would like to batch the queries. In raw SQL I'd return `commentId` and `userId` in every row, such that I can group the results by these fields. But I can't find a way to return the original `commentId` with Prisma to generalize the query to work with a list of `commentId` - `userId` pairs.

Is there a way to accomplish this with Prisma, or I am missing something? I am aware that making two requests could solve this, but that would result in an involved logic, plus I'd rather avoid making two DB roundtrips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prisma 2.0 already has a Dataloader built in exactly for this purpose. This means your resolvers might do multiple calls to `findOne` but those will be batched into one big SQL query under the hood. So there should be no need for you to implement this optimization on your own.